# My intent is null but I should get an intent from my Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, usb

I am new to android development and I struggle on this problem for a while, it would be really nice if you can help me. :)

I try to build an App where I can transfer data between my mobile phone (it is the Host) and an Arduino board. I struggle with recognizing my UsbDevice. I get asked on my Phone if want to grant the permission. But I can't proceed because the intent from the Receiver is null and then my intent I try to write to my usbDevice in my usbConnection class is of course also null. I worked with the official doc of Google.

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.maturaproject02;

import static com.example.maturaproject02.UsbConnection.ACTION_USB_PERMISSION;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    UsbConnection usbConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            usbConnection = new UsbConnection(this);
        } catch (noUsbDeviceException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Initialisierung des BroadcastReceivers
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        this.registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);

        // Initialisierung der RecyclerView
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvChatItems);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

// Hinzufügen des ItemDecorators
        int verticalSpacing = 1;  // Sie können den Wert ändern, um den Abstand zu erhöhen oder zu verringern
        VerticalSpacingItemDecorator itemDecorator = new VerticalSpacingItemDecorator(verticalSpacing);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);

// Setzen des Adapters
        ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton addContactButton = findViewById(R.id.addContactButton);
        addContactButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.input_name_layout, null);
            EditText newName = view1.findViewById(R.id.newName);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                    .setTitle("Kontakt benennen")
                    .setView(view1)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> {
                        String name = newName.getText().toString();
                        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.input_id_layout, null);
                        EditText newID = view2.findViewById(R.id.newID);
                        AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                                .setTitle("ID setzen")
                                .setView(view2)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog2, which2) -> {
                                    int id = Integer.parseInt(newID.getText().toString());
                                    Contact newContact = new Contact(name, id, new ArrayList<String>());
                                    contactAdapter.addContact(newContact);
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", null)
                                .create();
                        alertDialog2.show();

                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", null)
                    .create();
            alertDialog.show();

        });
    }

    private static final String TAG = "UsbConnection";
    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "111111111111111111111111111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    usbConnection.setDeviceIntent(intent);
                    if (usbConnection.getDeviceIntent() == null) {
                        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "2222222222222222222222222222222222", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (device != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "33333333333333333333333333333" + device, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                usbConnection.setDeviceIntent(intent);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "permission denied for device " + device, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device " + device);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And this is my usbConnection class, maybe it helps:

```
package com.example.maturaproject02;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import com.hoho.*;

import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialDriver;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialPort;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialProber;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class UsbConnection {

    private static final String INTENT_ACTION_GRANT_USB = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".GRANT_USB";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.maturaproject02.USB_PERMISSION";
    private UsbManager usbManager;
    private UsbDevice usbDevice;
    private UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection;
    private UsbInterface usbInterface;
    private UsbEndpoint usbEndpointIn;
    private UsbEndpoint usbEndpointOut;
    private PendingIntent permissionIntent;
    private Intent deviceIntent;
    private boolean messageSent = false;


    public UsbConnection(Context context) throws noUsbDeviceException {
        permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE); //vielleicht auch PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE lt gpt muss ab API 31 einer der beiden werte bei pending intent sein
        usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        if(!deviceList.isEmpty())
            usbDevice = deviceList.values().iterator().next();

        if(usbDevice != null) {
            usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, permissionIntent); //maybe usbDevice is not a usbAccessory
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No USB device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (deviceIntent == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "intent is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            messageSent = true;
        } else {
            usbDevice = deviceIntent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (usbDevice == null && !messageSent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No USB device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                messageSent = true;
            }
            usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(usbDevice);
            if (usbDeviceConnection == null && !messageSent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No USB device connection found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                messageSent = true;
            }
            usbInterface = usbDevice.getInterface(0);
            if (usbDevice == null && !messageSent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No USB device found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                messageSent = true;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < usbInterface.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                UsbEndpoint endpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(i);
                if(endpoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                    usbEndpointIn = endpoint;
                } else {
                    usbEndpointOut = endpoint;
                }
            }

        }
        if(!messageSent)
            Toast.makeText(context, "FINISHED CONSTRUCTORS WITHOUT ERRORS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    public void write(String message) {
if(usbDeviceConnection != null) {
            usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointOut, message.getBytes(), message.length(), 1000);
        }
    }


    public byte[] read() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[usbEndpointIn.getMaxPacketSize()];
        if(usbDeviceConnection != null) {
            usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointIn, bytes, bytes.length, 1000);
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    public void setDeviceIntent(Intent deviceIntent) {
        this.deviceIntent = deviceIntent;
    }

    public Intent getDeviceIntent() {
        return deviceIntent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indicate where in the code you are getting `null`. It isn't clear what your problem is.

Comment: The constructor of `UsbConnection` is being called in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`. At that time `deviceIntent` will be `null` because it hasn't been set yet. Please explain more about your architecture and how this should work.

Answer (score 1):

`PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` should probably be `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Should that fix my Problem because it didn't work. :(
Sorry for my bad english and if my message seems sassy

Comment: Getting the Mutability of Pending Intents wrong is a common mistake, an Immutable Pending Intent cannot be changed as it is used. Pre Android 12 all Pending Intents were Mutable. But not all uses of Pending Intents need to it be Mutable. Thus it was worth a quick try in changing it.